# Run several commands with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible 1.9 and want to run two commands. I have tried several variations:

```
- name: npm build
  command: npm run build
  args:
    chdir: "{{ app_dir }}"

- name: clean up
  shell: sed_index.sh
  args:
    chdir: "{{ app_dir }}"
```

On running I get the following error:

```
"stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found"
```

However

```
npm run build
```

works fine when I log in to the server and run it in the app_dir.

I also tried:

```
- name: npm install and clean
  command: "{{ item }} chdir={{ app_dir }}"
    with_items:
      - npm run build
      - sed_index.sh
```

Again I get a npm not found error.

If I comment out the npm run build command I get an error when running the sed_index script on the 'cd dist' command below, saying 'dist' not found.

sed_index.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd dist
sed -i 's|=static/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet>|=/app/static/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet>|g' index.html
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The npm executable is probably not in a standard location like /usr/bin/npm. Probably /usr/local/bin/npm, but it's up to you to find where it's installed and use the fully qualified path. From a login that can run the npm command, execute 'which npm'. The output will be what you want to use instead of just npm.

FYI - When I'm doing a one-off or other small task that I don't want to take the time to write a playbook for, if it's not an easy one liner in Ansible I write a small script to execute via the script module. One of the first commands in those scripts is to set the PATH if I know some of the commands are in non-standard locations.

Answer (score 1):

Use full path to the `npm` executable. Ansible runs commands in non-interactive shell session and your environment set in rc files is not read.

Regarding the second problem: if you get a "'dist' not found" error, it means either `dist` directory does not exist, or you call it from a wrong directory. It's impossible to tell given the information you provided.

Comment: I added npm run build to shell script on the server then ran it with  command: "{{ app_dir }}/npm_build.sh" but I get a npm: command not found error. npm is installed globally on the server so Im not sure why that would be

Comment: @techrat, sorry but I dont understand for you have answered my question?. npm does exist on the server and I expect I should be able to run it from any directory. Regarding the sed_index.sh, the dist directory exists but I may need to run all the commands therein from ansible instead of a script on the server as I have no idea on how to get the script to recognize the directory it is currently in on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to help you with understanding the English language.

Comment: What @techraf is trying to say is to replace **npm** with the fully qualified path. Likely it's not at /usr/bin/npm. Probably **/usr/local/bin/npm**, but it's up to you to find where it's installed and use the correct path. From a login that can run the npm command, execute `which npm`. The output will be what you want to use instead of just npm.

Comment: FYI - When I'm doing a one-off or other small task that I don't want to take the time to write a playbook for, if it's not an easy one liner in Ansible I write a small script to execute via the script module. One of the first commands in those scripts is to set the PATH if I know some of the commands are in non-standard locations.

Comment: @Deathgrip If you put these 2 responses in an answer I will accept as I found this advice the best solution to my problem.

Comment: @proximacentauri - Done. Just curious, where is the npm executable on the system you're working on?

Comment: @Deathgrip myhome/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/npm I used https://github.com/creationix/nvm to allow for multiple node versions

Comment: I was going mention that it could be underneath your $HOME if installed on a system that you don't have root privileges on. Glad I could help (actually @techraf had the correct answer, but he didn't quite explain it clearly). Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 1):

@techraf answer should help you to solve this issue.

For some reason if you look for an alternate way, give a try like below with ansible command:

```
ansible -m shell -a "/bin/bash -c 'cd {{app_dir}} && npm run build && ./sed_index.sh'" -e "app_dir=/path/to/app_dir" <host/group name>
```

You should be able to convert it back to your playbook once you get it running.